# JS: slice a nested array in array of objects by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

The task is to slice a nested array by `data` property.
I have the following array structure:

```
  const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];
```

Here's the method I use:

```
const sliceArray = mockData => mockData.map(d => ({...d, data: d.data.slice(0, 3)}))
```

It goes through all nested objects and slice array by `data` property, but how can I do it for a specific nested object instead of all of them?
I'd like to use `text` property as a key.

So, if I pass `Text1` to a method - `data` property in the first object only should be sliced and the output should be:

```
 const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];
```

If I pass 'Text2':

```
 const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
       data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }]
    }
  ];
```

What can be the solution? Thank you!

Comment: how will the desired output look like?

Comment: There's an output in the question. So, if I pass `Text1` only in object with a 'text' =  Text1, `data` array should be sliced. Other objects should remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another parameter to your function and check if the text matches that parameter.

```js
 const mockData = [{"text":"Text1","data":[{"field":"1"},{"field":"2"},{"field":"3"},{"field":"4"},{"field":"5"},{"field":"6"}]},{"text":"Text2","data":[{"field":"1"},{"field":"2"},{"field":"3"},{"field":"4"}]}]

const sliceArray = (data, target, len = 3) => 
  data.map(({ text, data, ...rest}) => ({
    data: text == target ? data.slice(0, len) : data,
    text,
    ...rest
  }))

console.log(sliceArray(mockData, 'Text1'))
```

You could also pass an array of text values that you want to match and use `includes` method for checking.

```js
 const mockData = [{"text":"Text1","data":[{"field":"1"},{"field":"2"},{"field":"3"},{"field":"4"},{"field":"5"},{"field":"6"}]},{"text":"Text2","data":[{"field":"1"},{"field":"2"},{"field":"3"},{"field":"4"}]}, {"text":"Text3","data":[{"field":"1"},{"field":"2"},{"field":"3"},{"field":"4"},{"field":"5"},{"field":"6"}]}]

const sliceArray = (data, targets, len = 3) => 
  data.map(({ text, data, ...rest}) => ({
    data: targets.includes(text) ? data.slice(0, len) : data,
    text,
    ...rest
  }))

console.log(sliceArray(mockData, ['Text1', 'Text3']))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add a condition like this:

```
const sliceArray = (mockData, text) => 
                     mockData.map(d => d.text === text 
                        ? {...d, data: d.data.slice(0, 3)} 
                        : d)
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you dont wanna to modify existing data, Since you are mocking. use reduce**

```js
const mockData = [
  {
    text: "Text1",
    data: [
      { field: "1" },
      { field: "2" },
      { field: "3" },
      { field: "4" },
      { field: "5" },
      { field: "6" }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Text2",
    data: [{ field: "1" }, { field: "2" }, { field: "3" }, { field: "4" }]
  }
];

function update(data, text, count = 3) {
  return data.reduce((arr, item) => {
    let updatedItem = { ...item };
    if (item.text === text) {
      updatedItem.data = (updatedItem.data || []).slice(0, count);
    }
    arr.push(updatedItem);
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

console.log("%j", update(mockData, "Text1"));
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```